# Sharing content from web page to instagram

Tags: vue.js, instagram, sharing

Cannot find any opportunity to post content from my page to Instagram directly, without usage of web share api. Is it evet possible to share from my page link, title, img ect. to instagram post/story/direct message?

Or if we anyway should use web share api, can we leave there only instagram related variant but no other ways to share content, like fb, whatsapp ect.?

Have tried to share post on Facebook by adding necessary attributes in url, and used vue-social-sharing npm package, which by the way doesn't contain Instagram as possible option

Comment: Did you get any info regarding this?